# Layer styling using raster symbology in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, dem, hillshade

I have two lists of raster (digital elevation model - DEM) layers by name. The first list of layers should be symbolized as follows:
symbology should be set to hillshade
layer rendering, blend mode should be set to soft light

[image]

and transparency, global opacity should be set to 30%

[image]

The second list of layers should be symbolized as follows:
symbology should be set to singleband pseudocolor
mode should be set to equal interval
and classes should be set to 5

[image]

I want to apply all of these settings with PyQGIS code because I need to set them manually every single time.

---

I have managed to partially solve the aforementioned set of problems.
The code for the first list of rasters (sets all the parameters properly):

```
`for i in list_1 :
    layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(i)[0]
    r = QgsHillshadeRenderer(layer_1.dataProvider(), 1, 315, 45)
    layer_1.setRenderer(r)
    layer_1.setBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_SoftLight)
    layer_1.renderer().setOpacity(0.3)`
```

The code for the second list of rasters (only part of the solution):

```
`for i in list_2 :
    layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(i)[0]
    sbps = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer_2.dataProvider(),1,)
    layer_2.setRenderer(sbps)`
```

How do I set Mode to Equal Interval and Classes to 5?